# Getting the Accessibility Display Size Programmatically Android

Tags: android, accessibility

I need to record certain metrics for the usage of my app based on font and display size. How can I retrieve the display size under Settings -> Accessibility section programmatically? Font Scale is straight-forward, but there seems to be no way of retrieving the display size.

```
float fontScale = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;
```

Comment: Unable to get font size by using:
float fontScale = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android API does not expose this scale factor chosen by the user. However, a similar scale can be obtained by dividing the density DPI (which is scaled based on the user's setting) and DENSITY_DEVICE_STABLE, which gives the required result.

```
final DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
final int currentDeviceDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
float displayDensityScaleFactor = (float) currentDeviceDensity / DENSITY_DEVICE_STABLE;
```

Comment: Might be worth adding that DENSITY_DEVICE_STABLE requires API level 24.

Comment: On API 31 this doesn't seem to work. In the specific Pixel 5 emulator I'm running, it reports 440 for both values, meaning the result is `1`. This is always the same regardless of what size the font is set in Accessibility...

Comment: ...so the value you want is `scaledDensity`.